# Why does the initial rotation of this cube not take effect on first render call?

Tags: three.js

I want to render a still image of a rotated cube. The following shows the cube, but it is not rotated. If I call that last line `renderer.render(scene, camera);` twice in a row, it renders the rotated cube as I would expect with only a single call. Can someone explain this to me? Seems odd I would have to do this to render a static 3D scene.

```
/* globals THREE, window, document */
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 5;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 'red'
      });


var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.rotation.x = 40 * Math.PI/180;
cube.rotation.y = 40 * Math.PI/180;
cube.position.z = 1;
var box = new THREE.BoxHelper(cube);

scene.add( cube );
scene.add( box );

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this so we don't have to?

Comment: This looks like a three.js bug to me: http://jsfiddle.net/r64gL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the the cube to the scene after the box solves the issue.

```
scene.add( box );
scene.add( cube );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DznVa/)

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 500;
scene.add(camera);
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 'red'
 });

var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.rotation.x = 40 * Math.PI/180;
cube.rotation.y = 40 * Math.PI/180;
cube.position.z = 1;

var box = new THREE.BoxHelper(cube);

scene.add( box );
scene.add( cube );

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: This may be the issue, but the fix you gave was wrong (though the answer is in your fiddle). It works if the box is added to the scene before the cube.

I updated your fiddle to highlight a fix for the problem. Not sure if this was the intended behavior or not.